# Vlookup in same range within different sheets on a different Google Spreadsheet | Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I'm hoping to do a VLOOKUP in a different Google Sheet based on 2 criteria: sheet name and then the lookup value. My data looks something like this:

```
A1            B1              C1
Sheet_Name    Lookup_Value    Lookup_Value
Sheet_1       123456          =vlookup(B3,"Sheet_1!$A$1:$C$1000",2,false)
Sheet_1       987456          =vlookup(B4,"Sheet_1!$A$1:$C$1000",2,false)
Sheet_2       654123          =vlookup(B5,"Sheet_2!$A$1:$C$1000",2,false)
Sheet_3       959595          =vlookup(B6,"Sheet_3!$A$1:$C$1000",2,false)
Sheet_3       621346          =vlookup(B7,"Sheet_3!$A$1:$C$1000",2,false)
```

Is there a way I can choose the sheet in my vlookup equation based on the value in column A rather than going in manually and updating this?

Currently, I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
=vlookup(B3,importrange("key_here",indirect(A3)&"!A1:C1000"),2,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=vlookup(B3,INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!$A$1:$C$1000",2,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: Google doesn't require the indirect function. So what works is:

```
=vlookup(B3,importrange("key_here",A3&"!A1:C1000"),2,false)
```